# Deleting 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

Can some one tell me what is wrong in the for loop? When I run it, it interrupts. I tried to debug to see what is wrong, I noticed that in the for loop it just stops:

```
#define MAX_POPULATION 64
float **tr_pop;//Tournament candidates
float **matingPool;//Mating pool
tr_pop=new float *[m];
matingPool=new float *[m];
for(l=0;l<m+1;l++)//allocating
{
    tr_pop[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION];
    matingPool[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION];
}
for ( int r = 0; r < row; ++r )//deleting
{
 delete [] matingPool[r];//Stops here (not ending program just frozen)
 delete [] tr_pop[r];
}
delete [] tr_pop;
delete [] matingPool;
```

=======OK. PROBLEM SOLVED=======

Here is the reason:

I just changed the `MAX_POPULATION` into the `MAX_POPULATION+1` and it worked.

```
for(l=0;l<m+1;l++)
    {
    tr_pop[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION+1];
    matingPool[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION+1];
    }
```

Because in another function I think I was doing violation:

```
void crossover()
{
int p1,p2,i,j;float tempBit;
p1=m/3;
p2=(2*m)/3;
for(j=0;j<MAX_POPULATION;j++)
{
    for(i=p1;i<p2;i++)
    {
    tempBit=matingPool[i][j];
    matingPool[i][j]=matingPool[i][j+1];//THE VIOLATION POINT (I THINK)
    matingPool[i][j+1]=tempBit;
    }
    j++;
}
```

As you can see, when `j = MAX_POPULATION` at the end of the loop, i was trying to reach `MAX_POPULATION + 1`. So I changed the allocations for columns, and the problem solved :)

Comment: Please post how ``matingPool`` and ``tr_pop`` is created.

Comment: Are all of the arrays in the inner array initialised? Check they aren't null before deleting.

Comment: @DarcyRayner: Deleting a null pointer is a no-op, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into undefined behavior:

```
for(l=0;l<m+1;l++)//allocating
{
    tr_pop[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION];
}
```

should be

```
for(l=0;l<m;l++)//allocating
{
    tr_pop[l]=new float[MAX_POPULATION];
}
```

You're allocating `m` elements for each of the arrays and try to access `m+1`.

Comment: in "l" loop, there is no problem. it just work. my problem is in the "r" loop.

Comment: @WhoCares: you have a problem with the `r` loop because your `l` loop is _wrong_. (And potentially other stuff, like what is `row` and how is it related to `m`?)

Comment: @Mat I changed my "l" loop like you guys said. still same. it doesnt delete the arrays of array. also it interrupts (actually not interrupts, just frozen) at beginning of "r" loop. So I think the problem is not the allocating, at least it should delete from tr_pop[0] to tr_pop[m-1]. I think there is wrong here something different

Comment: @WhoCares: we can't tell more with what you posted. Try and make an [scce](http://sscce.org/), or post the all the _relevant_ code. Problems during delete are 99.9% of the time a symptom of you doing something wrong before (sometimes long before) the delete.

Comment: @Mat it is weird. it works on linux perfectly, but on windows i dont know... anyway, thank u all

Comment: @WhoCares: that means you're doing something _really_ wrong (undefined behavior). Run your code through `valgrind`, compile it in 32bit & 64bit, turn all your compiler warnings to the max - you've got a latent bug in your code that you need to _fix_ now rather than later when it silently eats your data.

Comment: @Mat both arrays have exactly same definition. both arrays have same allocating. Now I found that: for ( int r = 0; r < m+1; ++r )
       `{
           delete [] tr_pop[r];
           delete [] matingPool[r];
       }` when I get the tr_pop front, it doesnt give any error. But at next line it just stops again, i mean `matingPool`

Comment: @WhoCares please post the sample that is giving you the error on www.ideone.com so we can replicate.

Comment: @Mat and LuchianGrigore the problem solved. I edited my question. thanks for help:)

Comment: @WhoCares the fixes are equivalent I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating `m` `float*` but in `for` loop you are iterating from `0..m` while allocating memory, it should from `0..m-1`. For that you need to chnage the `for` loop to : `for(l=0;l<m;l++)`.